# Lottie SVG duplicating after switching slides (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

I have a slider created with 3 scenes, after viewing scene 1 then viewing scene 2 when you go back to scene 1 the old lottie svg that displays after the animation completes is still there.
How would I add a listener or rework this code to where it kills the event when going to a new slide.

I'm a entry level dev so excuse my js if it's really basic,
I am hiding the other slides on click, this is through wordpress.

```
<script>

function seekButton() {
    
//lottie animation
var introToSeekv2 = lottie.loadAnimation({
container: document.getElementById('seek-container'),
renderer: 'svg',
loop: false,
autoplay: false,
path: '***links here',
});
    document.getElementById("solve-section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("transform-section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("seek-section").style.display = "block";
    
    // play lottie animation
    introToSeekv2.play();
}


function solveButton() {
    
var seekToSolve = lottie.loadAnimation({
container: document.getElementById('solve-container'),
renderer: 'svg',
loop: false,
autoplay: false,
path: '***links here',
});
    
    document.getElementById("seek-section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("transform-section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("solve-section").style.display = "block";
    
// play lottie animation
seekToSolve.play();
}


function transformButton() {
    
var solveToTransform = lottie.loadAnimation({
container: document.getElementById('transform-container'),
renderer: 'svg',
loop: false,
autoplay: false,
path: '***links here',
});
    document.getElementById("seek-section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("solve-section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("transform-section").style.display = "block";
    
    // play lottie animation
    solveToTransform.play();
}
```

[image: Before]

[image: when you go to another slide then go back]